How in Api-Platform Patch operation entity data is updated?
I want to create ApiResource Patch reqeust withouth identifier using custom persistor. And update only one of UserProfileApi fields (firstName or lastName) independently.
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/user/profile.{_format}',
//  uriTemplate: '/user/profile/{id}.{_format}',
    operations: [
        new Patch(
            provider: CustomItemStateProvider::class,
            processor: CustomEntityStateProcessor::class,
        ),
    ],
    stateOptions: new Options(entityClass: User::class),
)]
class UserProfileApi implements ApiResourceInterface
{
    #[ApiProperty(readable: false, writable: false, identifier: true)]
    public ?int $id = null;
    public ?string $firstName = null;
    public ?string $lastName = null;
}

Patch request body:
{"firstName":"John"}

If I am using identifier {id}in uriTemplate :uriTemplate: '/user/profile/{id}.{_format}'- all works fine.
I find, that CustomItemStateProvider is called and User Entity from Doctrine is provided.
readonly class CustomEntityStateProcessor implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
    $entity = $this->itemProvider->provide($operation, $uriVariables, $context);
    dump($entity)
...

And somehow in CustomEntityStateProcessor i am getting UserProfileApi ALREDY with updated firstName, and lastName is from database.
readonly class CustomEntityStateProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): ?ApiResourceInterface
    {    
    dump($data)
...

BUT IF I REMOVE {id} from uriTemplate
uriTemplate: '/user/profile

CustomItemStateProvider is NOT CALLED, and IN CustomEntityStateProcessor I AM GETTING UserProfileApi object with "firstName":"John" and "lastName":null. AND CustomEntityStateProcessor on persit try to create new user.
HOW I CAN PASS UserProfileApi request data and Entity data to CustomEntityStateProcessor to update in Entity only firstName, and all the rest entity data leave the same?
